# Why was Pathname's chdir method obsoleted?

Tags: ruby, obsolete

Why is Pathname's `chdir` method obsoleted since ruby 1.8.1? What is wrong with it?

This:

```
dir = Pathname('a')
dir.chdir do
  ...
end
```

is shorter and more readable than this:

```
dir = Pathname('a')
Dir.chdir(dir) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with it, `Pathname` just wasn't the right place for it.

Use `Dir.chdir` instead.

Source: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Pathname.html#M000633 (click "[Source]")

Comment: Still can't understand, added example.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`FileUtils.cd('/', :verbose => true)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/FileUtils.html#M003030)

Comment: It uses `Dir.chdir` … but you did not answer the question: why was it obsoleted, what is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm showing another alternate to use. Why it was obsoleted is probably a matter of record that can be discovered by searching.